# Is it possible to bind image change event in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have images on my page. For image changing I am using ajax. I have dataTable in which each row have an image and a(anchor) element. I am making an script in which I am trying to do that iterate over each row of table and if my image source attribute on each row contains the subString "no-preview.jpg", then hide the a(anchor) element of that row. Fine. But the problem is when my page loads then the script runs and hide all the remove links, but when I select an image and image updated using ajax, then the script do not run because of ajax.

Now I want to ask is there any event with the image that I can use to listen for image change. That is whenever my image scr attribute change, that event triggers in jQuery. May be I have to delegate the event .

### **Edit**

```
var saarcImages = $("#SaarcImage #saarcImagesTable tr").each(function(index){

    var $tr = $(this);
    var $image = $tr.find("img");

    if ($image.length != 0) {   //Image exist

        var imageSource = $image.attr("src");       
        var contains = imageSource.indexOf("no-preview.jpg") >= 0; // true
        if (contains) {

            $tr.find("a").fadeOut("slow");

        } else {

            $tr.find("a").fadeIn("slow");

        }
    }
}); //end of .each()
```

Comment: Post some code. From what I understand, you may need to bind your events using `$.on`.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you can't place the code which needs to run when the image is changed in a function, and simply call that after changing the image?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan rgin Actually i am using a framework, that framework do the ajax part. The script that i posted is running fine, but i have problem because of framework ajax. So what i am asking is this if i delegate a click event like `("img").delegate("click", function(){...})`, then whenever i click on the image, then this event run no matter i use ajax or not. So is there any event that tell me that image src attribute has changed, so when using ajax image updated and it's source changes then my event trigger? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options:

- listen to `load` event on the image, it should be called every time image is loaded,
- create your own event (eg. `imagechange`, preferably namespaced like `imagechange.mymodule`) and trigger it after each image change with jQuery's `.trigger()` function - it will call appropriate event handler (if you attach it),

Comment: How can i make my own event? Like i want that when each image on my page, has it's src attribute changes, then trigger my event. Thanks

Comment: You do it by attaching event handler to your own event name, like `$(some_selector).on('imagechange', function(){ ... })`, but still you will need to trigger it separately by using `$(some_selector).trigger('imagechange')` when you do something that should result in event handlers being triggered (eg. you change `src` within AJAX success callback).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
//YOUR AJAX CALL TO RETRIEVE IMAGE
$.post('yourURLhere',{myVar : myValue}, function(info) {

          //WAIT FOR IMAGE TO LOAD
          $('img[title="item_picture"]').load(function() {
                    //DO SOMETHING HERE ONCE IMAGE IS LOADED
          }); 

});
```